# MySql spanish character data

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

i hav a database that contains spanish characters. to populate the database i am getting the values from client page which has character encoding=UTF-8. when i insert the values in mySql database the rows contain altered data. for example if i insert 'México', the entry in the database is 'MÃ©xico'. the impact this has is when i do a query on the table specifying 'México', i get no results. my question is how do u insert spanish or other latin accent in mysql database? i hav tried all the collations, htmlentities() etc but nothing works!!
when making mysql query i checked what data is being sent and it is in its correct form 'México' but when i see the table entry through phpmyadmin, its altered!!

Comment: Your table’s character encoding is probably not UTF-8.

Comment: my tables collation is utf8_general_ci...is this the same? i mean character encoding and collation is the same thing?

Comment: [Collation and character encoding are different things.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-general.html)

Comment: thanks for the link...hw can i set my tables character encoding?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored explains how you can get Mojibake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your mysql database/ table / column  encoding to UTF-8 (and also set the collation to a compatible value).

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE mytable 
MODIFY country CHAR(50) 
CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Also specify the char set at the PHP side when connecting.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn);
```

Take a look at [this article](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/utf-8/mysql) for further info and a script to batch change every table / column in a database.

Comment: Anthony i cant query my database after inserting items in database...luks like the value doesnt matches the one i provide and the one in database!! i i also post this question in this form...dont knw hw to post the link

Comment: Salman, are you setting the utf8 encoding in the PHP side also when querying? (Second block of code). You must always use the same encoding (in this case utf8). If you insert using utf8 and query using the default charsert (probably ISO-8859-1) things will not work. Take a look at [this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) from the PHP manual.

Comment: not working :/ also, do you have a PDO version of the PHP command?

Answer (score 2):

I just wasted 4 hours on the same problem as you.

Everything is in UTF-8

EG:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

The MySQL database is in UTF-8 PHP is in UTF-8

After four hours and on many occasions tearing my hair out I have found a solution that works.

```
$content = htmlentities($row[mystring], ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
$content = html_entity_decode($content);
```

It takes the accents converts them to html characters then converts them back into UTF-8

This is a great hack and it works perfectly.

For some inexplicable reason, the data in my MYSQL database is not in the UTF-8 format even though I have gone to extreme measures like exporting the data to a text file in phpmyadmin saving it as  UTF-8 in a text editor and re-importing it. None of this worked.

Comment: 3 and a half years after you wrote this, I just want to say you've saved me hours of effort. This worked perfectly!

Comment: this didn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Check two things first:

- Are you inserting the data as UTF-8? If the data is coming from a web page, make sure the page's encoding is set to UTF-8 (encoding meta tag is set in the page header).
- Are you sure the data is not saved as Unicode? This is the reverse situation: if phpMyAdmin uses something else other than UTF-8, you'd see the garbled characters when it displays the contents.

Comment: before inserting i echo the data and its in the desired form...sorry i dint get ur second point...hw do i check if the data is saved as unicode or nt?

Comment: Echoing the data doesn't necessarily tell you anything if the page's encoding is wrong.