# Display HTML friendly special characters with PHP from a MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql

I'm from Mexico, so our strings contain some special characters that need to be stored and later displayed. Is there a way (using PHP) to encode a string from MySQL and use it in html?

```
  <?php 
    function especialidades($dbcesp){
        $q="SELECT NombreEspecialidad FROM especialidad;";
        $r=mysqli_query($dbcesp, $q);

        while ($esp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
            ?>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><?php echo $esp['NombreEspecialidad']; ?></button>
            <?php
        }
    } 
   ?>
```

This is the way I retrieve and generate some buttons for my webpage, but for some reason, aren't displayed correctly.

Comment: Please, consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php) as well.

Answer (score 3):

first go to your `phpmyadmin` then set `Server connection collation` to `utf8mb4_general_ci`

then select your `database name` then press on your `table` then press on `structure` you will see all columns inside your table go and change all columns using type `varchar` or `text` then go press on `change` the change the  `collation` to `utf8_general_ci`  then save then  try to input another entry to your database it will be clearly now without any fuzzing words

and the top of your code type

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and those lines in the top of your php code to define the utf charset

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Comment: It didn't work :( It doesn't show the original character

Comment: you are using phpmyadmin ?

Comment: check my answer again !

Answer (score 1):

You should configure database for using UTF-8. Also don't forget to set encoding on html to UTF-8 too.

Also, check the following link: [MySql spanish character data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7150622/mysql-spanish-character-data)

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the database collation to utf8_spanish_ci (during database creation in PHPMyAdmin).

Also, I had to add the charset meta tag to the html document:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

And finally, I used the PHP encode api, being used as follows:

```
  <?php 
function especialidades($dbcesp){
    $q="SELECT * FROM especialidad;";
    $r=mysqli_query($dbcesp, $q);

    while ($esp=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {
        ?>
        <a href="?page=6&esp=<?php echo $esp['CveEspecialidad']; ?>">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="<?php echo $esp['CveEspecialidad']; ?>">

                <?php
                    echo utf8_encode($esp['NombreEspecialidad']); 
                ?>

        </button>
        </a>
        <?php
    }
} 
?>
```

This worked for me